# How to use self page database update in Django?

Tags: django, forms, django-views

I have a question on my homepage that the user should answer through radio buttons. The user should press the submit button to send the answer, so basically it is a SELF PAGE submission. The user should not go to another page after submitting the answer but should remain on the same home page. Though I looked up some earlier questions, the code did not work out.

I have created the TEMPLATE DIRECTORY under the root folder and under this directory, there is a 'pages' folder that has the index.html (homepage) inside which I am invoking the form

The form code in the index.html page.

```
<form action = "?" method = "POST">
```

I want to know what function should I write in the views. Since the form action does not call a named view I am not able to figure out how I should define the view that updates the data.

```
def WHAT NAME SHOULD I GIVE HERE(request):
.....other code
```

I am adding the following code as of 3rd May. When I use this code I get the error. I would like to state that in the form the questions.id is coming from the questions model (or table) but in the function in the views, I want to update the question.id in the questionid field in the answers model

```
     ValueError at /updateans/updateans
     Cannot assign "''": "Answers.questionid" must be a "Questions" instance.
```

The relevant code in the form is

```
     <form action = "{% url 'updateans' %}" method = "POST">
     <input type = "hidden" name ="questionid" value = "{{Questions.id}}">
```

The function in the views file is (as of now I am just trying to update one field but still getting an error - see above)

```
  def updateans(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
     questionid = request.POST["questionid"] 'variable questionid defined
     print(questionid)  --> even the print command shows a blank
     myans = Answers(questionid=questionid)
     'questionid is a field in the Answers model
     myans.save()
```

Thanks

Comment: Then you need to make an AJAX request: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: Thanks. However, AJAX is used for UI and definitely I intend to use it. As of now, I want to know how I should name the function.

Comment: the name of the function does not matter, as long as you trigger it. AJAX is not UI, it is a mechanism of the frontend to talk in an *asynchronous* way to the backend, so it can be used to submit data, without fetching a new page.

Answer (score 0):

After Form Submission redirect the user to the same page

```
def answer_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST["name"]
        subject = request.POST["subject"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        message = request.POST["message"]
        con = Contact(name=name,subject=subject,email=email,message=message)
        con.save()
        # If u use messages module of django then the next line will work
        messages.success(request,"Thank you for contacting us, We will get to you as soon as possible")
        return redirect("home.html")
```

The is some thing like this u just need to redirect the user to same page

Comment: Hi Uday, thanks a lot for this code..this This is helpful. However when I write this in the form  <form action = "/answer_submit/" method = "POST">, I get an error that Page not found.

Comment: That means the url written in the form action doesnt exists in the matching urls.py,  can u please post ur urls.py so that i can figure it out

Comment: Hi  Uday, please see my updated post. I have mentioned the details.

Comment: in your form instead of  ``` <form action = "{% url 'updateans' %}" method = "POST"> ``` use ```<form action="/updateans" method='POST'> ``` and click on the form submit then see the address bar and copy the url and add it in urls.py and in views.py redirect to same page

Comment: Thanks, Uday. The navigation is working now however for some odd reason, the print command is not showing the output (questionid) and so the table is also not getting updated. I have tested it and the question.id is getting called correctly in the form but the function 'updateans' is not able to process it so the question.id does not show in the print command.

Comment: I tested it by trying to print hello only but it is still not getting printed. it seems the function updateans is not getting accessed at all

Comment: do u have team viewer or some conneting platforms .. or send the files to my mail 'kiranu941@gmail.com'

Comment: I have teamviewer. When can we connect?

Comment: yeah sure check out ur email